# XCopy one directory to another, starting from lowest size folder up-to the biggest folder in size

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

i have multiple folders with different sizes, and i want to move them using Xcopy , to another location starting from lowest size folder until the biggest one so it can be much faster.

my code as below

```
xcopy "\\10.4.32.124\PapyrusRes\605000319" "\\Dxb-raso-mch\server-EPSO\605000319" /e /c /h /y
```

thanks

Comment: Please edit your post and add what did you tried as code until now !

Comment: @Hackoo done check it plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use robocopy. because it is more flexible and faster. 
(windows 7 and later)

For more information start\run\cmd -->

robocopy /?

thanks